# Listview android - change height after data load dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a android layout like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/headingView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/value_5dp">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/mt_gray_color"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itemHeading"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="#f2f2f2"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mylist"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/value_5dp"
                android:minHeight="500dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

- I am loading data dynamically in ListView after this page/fragment has been loaded.
- The listview contains more than one element and I was expecting that it will show me list in the listview without scrolls as I have made it WRAP_CONTENT.

I might have wrong understanding and which what I want to understand and find a solution that how can i avoid the scroll bars and have all the items listed in the listview without scrolls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The concept of ListView is to List down the Items . Each row is individual entity contain default or user defined layout. Your question is a bit confusing what you are trying to achieve and what hurdles you are facing in achieving that

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the size off all children of the `ListView` at runtime and then set it's height to the total height of all the children combined. You can use this method:

```
public void justifyListView(ListView listView) {

    ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();

    if (adapter == null) {
        return;
    }
    ViewGroup vg = listView;
    int totalHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, vg);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = listView.getLayoutParams();
    par.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(par);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of listView when the data changed.